# Model shows only c generation

Tags: uml-designer

I have UML-generator installed, including java and c generator.

When I right click on a class it allows me only C code (and reverse) but not java.

Any hint that it also allows me to generate java ?

Comment: You should reference the uml-generator you're using; as it stands, your question is unclear.  Otherwise, the only correct answer is: "If it says 'java generator', then that is a hint that it should allow you to generate java code", which is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it means that the java generator is not well installed. The UML generator project is not today part of UML Designer so you have to ask the questions related to the generator on the dedicated Eclipse forum.

In order to simplify the usage of the generators, we decided to include them directly in the UML Designer product since the next release 8.0 in July. It should be easier to use in a near future. See the related issue:  https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/921

Comment: Thank you Mélanie, I will wait then for the release 8. If I need it e
arlier I will try to reinstall the the java gen / remove the C gen. 
Basically i think it is good that you include it into the UML designer. As RSA has its generator also built in. It works much better as it can be fine tuned to work with UML designer